# c# Console Alternative

Tags: c#

whats the best alternative to the traditional System.Console ?

Comment: You mean you want to write text in a multiline textbox?

Comment: Does it need to be console only. What you want to do would be really easy in winforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A multiline RichTextBox is what you'd want to use.
Drag a RichTextBox from your toolbox onto the form. In the properties windows change the Multiline property to True, and resize the textbox as you wish.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cool Example:

```
Using System; // <-- You need this for Console

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    //
    // 1. Type "Console" and press "."
    // 2. Select "BackgroundColor".
    // 3. Press space and "=", then press tab.
    //
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.WriteLine("White on blue.");
    Console.WriteLine("Another line."); // <-- This line is still white on blue.
    Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to illustrate with this example exactly?  What are all the comments referring to - and what do they have to do with this question?  A description of the code would be helpful.